# Does this integral equation have a unique solution? If so, how might I go about finding it?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, integro-differential-equations

I have the following relationship
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty W_1(x,y)\Gamma(x,y)dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty W_2(x,y)\Gamma(x,y)dxdy=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Gamma(x,y)dxdy
\end{equation}
where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, $W_1$ and $W_2$ are real valued functions, but $\Gamma$ is generally complex valued. Everything is known except $\Gamma$. Is $\Gamma$ uniquely defined by this relationship (barring $\Gamma=0$)? If so, how might one solve for it? And if not, how can I see that? I also know that
\begin{align}
0&\leq\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Gamma(x,y)dxdy\right|<1 & &\text{and} & \int_{-\infty}^\infty W_1(x,y)dxdy&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty W_2(x,y)dxdy=1
\end{align}

Thanks in advance and please let me know if there's anything I can clarify!

Edit: I also should note that $W_1\neq W_2$, and further that
\begin{equation}
2\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(W_1(x,y)\right)^2dxdy=2\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty (W_2(x,y))^2dxdy=1
\end{equation}
This last relation comes from the fact that $W_1$ and $W_2$ are Wigner functions of pure quantum states. The norm of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Gamma dxdy$ is also known, but not the phase.

Comment: I don't see any chance for this. It should be easy to construct examples of multiple $\Gamma$s in the case $W_1=W_2$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for the reply! I should have mentioned that $W_1$ strictly does not equal $W_2$. Even in that case is your feeling that the solution is not unique?

Comment: For starters if $\Gamma$ is a solution then $a\Gamma$ is too.

Comment: Yes, it is still a very strange question. The values of the integral of $\Gamma$ against a finite number of functions has no chance of determining $\Gamma$ completely.